# Dropdown of available statuses

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to figue out what I"m doing wrong to get the error message. I have my User model that has a status_id field and it is a foreign key to my statuses table with an id and name field.

```
public function scopeAvailable($query, $current = null)
{
    $options = $this->getAvailableOptions($current)->toArray();

    return $query->whereIn('name', $options);
}

public function getAvailableOptions(string $current = null)
{

    $options = collect(['Active', 'Inactive']);

    switch ($current) {
        case 'Active':
            return $options->merge(['Fired', 'Suspended', 'Retired']);

        case 'Injured':
            return $options->merge(['Fired', 'Retired']);

        case 'Suspended':
            return $options->merge(['Suspended', 'Retired']);
    }

    return $options;
}

public function availableStatuses()
{
    $status = $this->status ? $this->status->name : null;

    return UserStatus::available($status)->get();
}
```

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Models\UserStatus::getAvailableOptions() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in /home/vagrant/projects/app/app/Models/UserStatus.php on line 45

Comment: You're passing an object when calling the getAvailableOptions method. Looking at line 45 in UserStatus.php will confirm that.

Comment: But it should be either a string or null how is $status an object at the point.

Comment: You haven't shared that code with us, so can't answer.